# How to display a string within a text file? (C# Console Application)

Tags: c#, regex, io, console

So, I found out how to display the number of occurrences of an input string, but I do not know how to display how the word looks and the sentence the word it is in. For example, my input string was "the", but how would I display it as The or THE or withered on the console? Also, how would I display this input string with the sentence it is in? For example: "the", sentence: The drought withered the bus.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string line;
        int counter = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a word to search for: ");
        string userText = Console.ReadLine();

        string file = "Gettysburg.txt";
        StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(file);

        int found = 0;

        while ((line = myFile.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            counter++;
            if (line.IndexOf(userText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found on line number: {0}", counter);
                found++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("A total of {0} occurences found", found);
    }
```

Comment: Add another Console.WriteLine to show word and the sentence inside the IF condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you would like to have the word that triggered the match, even if it was a partial word of your match.

```
while ((line = myFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    counter++;
    int index = line.IndexOf(userText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    if (index != -1)
    {
        //Since we want the word that this entry is, we need to find the space in front of this word
        string sWordFound = string.Empty;
        string subLine = line.Substring(0, index);
        int iWordStart = subLine.LastIndexOf(' ');
        if (iWordStart == -1)
        {
            //If there is no space in front of this word, then this entry begins at the start of the line
            iWordStart = 0;
        }

        //We also need to find the space after this word
        subLine = line.Substring(index);
        int iTempIndex = subLine.LastIndexOf(' ');
        int iWordLength = -1;
        if (iTempIndex == -1)
        {    //If there is no space after this word, then this entry goes to the end of the line.
            sWordFound = line.Substring(iWordStart);
        }
        else
        {
            iWordLength = iTempIndex + index - iWordStart;
            sWordFound = line.Substring(iWordStart, iWordLength);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Found {1} on line number: {0}", counter, sWordFound);
        found++;
    }
}
```

This may have bugs, but should push you in the right direction. Also, it would be helpful in your example if you included expected output.

This is what I would expect out of this code:

```
input:
The drought withered the bus.
Luke's father is well known.
The THE ThE

output:
Found The on line number: 1
Found withered on line number: 1
Found the on line number: 1
Found father on line number: 2
Found The on line number: 3
Found THE on line number: 3
Found ThE on line number: 3
```

Comment: Hi, so after using your code, there was an error in the string subline code because it was used twice. Is the second string subline a different string? I renamed it string subline2 and it was able to work. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Another question, how would I make the console output the actual word that contains "the". For example it would be like 

Found "THE" in THE Gettysburg on line number 1.


Found "fathers" in fathers brought forth on this on line number 4

Comment: Glad it was able to work for you. Yep, it shouldn't have been declared twice. Renaming it is a valid solution. I meant to reuse the variable. Corrected in the above.

sWordFound should contain the word found (searching the with the line "fathers" should return "fathers"). I may not have the correct syntax for the writeline.

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified the output better. It should display the word "fathers" and then the sentence. For example: Found "fathers" in the sentence: fathers brought forth on this on line number: 4

Comment: Since the string = line in my code represents the entire sentence, is it possible to make sFoundWord just to have to have a singular word containing "the"?

Comment: I edited my answer to have an input with expected output. My sWordFound contains the full word that was found.  If you just want the search term's word (ie: "withered" returns "the") then my example is far too complicated. Then you are probably wanting: if(index != -1) { string sWordFound = line.Substring(index, userText.length); }

Answer (score 0):

How about change one line:

```
Console.WriteLine("Line {0}: {1}", counter,line);
```

By the way, I don't quite understand your question, what does it mean by "display it as The or THE or withered on the console", and "display this input string with the sentence it is in"?